# OpenSceneGraph FirstPerson Walking Camera

Tags: c++, openscenegraph

I am new to OpenSceneGraph and would appreciate help figuring out which of the existing CameraManipulator classes, or even any out there, I would need to use for Walking/Running/Jogging simulations. So far I have checked out about 10 of the manipulators but none of them seem to do what I need here which is simulate walking/jogging/running with ease.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about FirstPersonManipulator (formerly DoomLikeManipulator)
https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/blob/master/src/osgGA/FirstPersonManipulator.cpp

Comment: Broken link! :(